# theta and theta2 chanel encoding by field

Tags: vega-lite

I want to create arcs using vega-lite, here you will find a working example: [enter link description here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXADgAwBoRwKYQOZwxJqYAOAhgE7kC2AzkgNqgB2t2SI1UEArg5gBu5ADa8OiVAF90rdp2586AJhBDR4pAFZpAXUxRyMcklDCx2BomYg2NCSCoBjAIxqQAR17ko1FkUQQABUAe1IAJXxCd0oIFjxOAAkQkSgQKV0ZEBg-OgAzEMoaJlAnUSdeESMHCDyACkMYXhoAOi8fPxgAAgBePq6AclCIqJgBrq70LoAFAEkAKlQWrUmulkqRAEp3citswnJVGVLyyurOWoajZrbvX3J-Xv6hsMiCMYmp1FX1kS2dvbwYzpfQgGhUADWpmyAE9SA5nDEfEpodgAB6kSgKZH8dKYRT8VSIUDozHYniE9JZbAsJwhHjxaHwbDA4kgcyaNmkrGBRo3IEmKRZZnGIlmDQSEkYnkgPmtAVHIVSIA)

but this does not work: [enter link description here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXADgAwBoRwKYQOZwxJqYAOAhgE7kC2AzkgNqgB2t2SI1UEArg5gBu5ADa8OiVAF90rdp2586AJhBDR4pAFZpAXUxRyMcklDCx2BomYg2NCSCoBjAIxqQAR17ko1FkUQQABUAe1IAJXxCd0oIFjxOAAkQkSgQKV0ZEBg-OgAzEMoaJlAnUSdeESMHCDyACkMYXhoAOi8fPxgAAgBePq6AclCIqJgBrq70LoAFAEkAKlQWrUmulkqRAEp3citswnJVGVLyyurOWoajZrbvX3J-Xv6hsMiCMYmp1FX1kS2dvbwYzpfQgGhUADWpmyAE9SA5nDEfEpodgAB6kSgKZH8dKYRT8VSIUDozHYniE9JZbAsJwhHjxaHwbDA4kgPIQbCpThAkxZZnGImgDlctKBXlHKRSIA)

The difference is only that I use this in the working example

```
"encoding": {
"theta": {"value": {"expr": "datum.thta"}},
"theta2": {"value": {"expr": "datum.thta2"}}  }
```

And this is the code that does not work:

```
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "thta"}, 
"theta2": {"field": "thta2"}}  }
```

Can someone explain why using the "fields" creates a half circle (not wanted) and "value" creates the quarter circle (wanted)?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify values via encodings, the scale is automatically adjusted based on the content of the data. You can fix this by specifying that the scale should be from 0 to 2pi ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXADgAwBoRwKYQOZwxJqYAOAhgE7kC2AzkgNqgB2t2SI1UEArg5gBu5ADa8OiVAF90rdp2586AJhBDR4pAFZpAXUxRyMcklDCx2BomYg2NCSCoBjAIxqQAR17ko1FkUQQABUAe1IAJXxCd0oIFjxOAAkQkSgQKV0ZEBg-OgAzEMoaJlAnUSdeESMHCDyACkMYXhoAOi8fPxgAAgBePq6AclCIqJgBrq70LoAFAEkAKlQWrUmulkqRAEp3citswnJVGVLyyurOWoajZrbvX3J-Xv6hsMiCMYmp1FX1kS2dvbwYzpfQgGhUADWpmyAE9SA5nDEfEpodgAB6kSgKZH8dKYRT8VSIUDozHYniE9JZbAsJwhHjxaHwbDA4kgPIQbCpThAkyYOhlEQSUBQELguJMDAANhaymQmSyzOMRNAHK5aUCvKOUikQA)):

```json
{
  "width": 80,
  "height": 80,
  "params": [{"name": "radius", "value": 0}, {"name": "radius2", "value": 50}],
  "data": {
    "values": [{"name": "arc1", "quadrant": "TopRight", "ring": "Hold"}]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "if(datum.quadrant === 'TopRight'  , PI*0.5 , null)",
      "as": "thta2"
    },
    {"calculate": "if(datum.quadrant === 'TopRight'  , 0 , null)", "as": "thta"}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "arc",
    "radius": {"expr": "radius"},
    "radius2": {"expr": "radius2"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "thta", "scale": {"domain": [0, "2*PI"]}},
    "theta2": {"field": "thta2"}
  }
}
```

[image]