# follow up question: theta and theta2 chanel encoding by field

Tags: vega-lite

this is a follow-up question to my previous question: [theta and theta2 chanel encoding by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710123/theta-and-theta2-chanel-encoding-by-field)

Here is a working example, now the data is more complete (5 arcs instead of 1, but 11 are still missing): [5 arcs](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAFgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxAAcBDAJ0oFsBnJAbVADt6ckRaoIBXBgCYQWHAA9y1bnQhsAFJFhwMAAlwEiASgD0IgL4Z2nbgyoBjOfnIB7OTCZYAbpQA2-LogCs+gLpYoShhKJFAXdxwmRFYQDjpPEAAVACUAfQBJURAAR35KKFo2YkQkm3JkzWIsaituTMNjeO4AITT0zKxc-MLikGabGBgbOgrCKp5akvaQBtiTEuaAGQzpzryCyiKWgaG6RZwAM3Gatnw66dm4hMTl9o6c9Z7uRLL9o6yTs6mLozmmkpuGQAalkuhstgDXodjpMQOkQX5DCAYIUGAcbNQ6CxQOY3OZ+K4ggkIAd5IEYPw6AA6T6qAC8DNUAHJ0kzVKo1LwBMIALTycx4VzyLmCIQ6ZBaHlmSiWU62ewMLQc1QkslBSk0qz0xks1nszn5blCPkCiBCkXCcVaABUxulsusdiKiuVqvJGtpDLpzLubOVFuN-MFwsNoqt1oAzFKLFZ5c6lWo3erqZ6dfC-Qa+KKTcGA+HkNGZbGnQ4E6o2ATXFpq1ospQojws0xZrjXPjCTBiaT3SmtV6fRnVAHXd3k5rTtrvbrBwGc2aQ02xRKy0mKb2J-3dXr-aHeUH53mJbaV6O1+P8JOfUCZ7vA6bzbfwxGyxXXFWa3WG9RFzNfq320S3CrhqYI9JeTIvOUlSDqgI5qmeoGbDA4H9IMwyjEQg4AArpNaqBUl4cE9lSiFFChOzDG8MDYekRFjqRyGbpBVE0daACMBHKq+77Vp+3DwMEv44niBKASUwHUgx4GQRh1H6qoOF4ZxianiBjxIeRaEjNB8k4XRCHqWRm6obsLG6bhHGESp8Fqd0GlMVCRysUIXGVjWtZYPW-FEJQBj+CAdA0AA1qEyIAJ7kAkNDmFk8A4IJiCgBIUjcKgv4gOYNiuBi3DUDgUDpTgbCZXwpyhRaoXhB4oXJdIJTEd+3IzEiAaVW41WJSAtXcA1P76EicUJWE7WeElkh1SAxECSE-VYINvltRENXjT1Y7TQYSKZdldWgAcEA4K4BUlFcsURQkbDDHIbhZK4OD4EVR3cVgDCtqNk3DJQcgsEkbRZK0Kx-bcqxJED9yAvCID+YU93fXlBVYAAxMg5gAOwAByUGjKNeFk+B5UVWRI6jGNo14aWI8j6OY0IOO+P1-VAA)

I'm using this code to encode the channels radius, radius2, theta, and theta2

```
"radius": {"value": {"expr": "datum.rdius"}},
"radius2": {"value": {"expr": "datum.rdius2"}},
"theta": {"value": {"expr": "datum.thta"}},
"theta2": {"value": {"expr": "datum.thta2"}},
```

but what I want is using the field notation style, but unfortunately I'm not able to get the scaling right.
The link to the spec that is not working: [5 arcs not working](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAFgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxAAcBDAJ0oFsBnJAbVADt6ckRaoIBXBgCYQWHAA9y1bnQhsAFJFhwMAAlwEiASgD0IgL4Z2nbgyoBjOfnIB7OTCZYAbpQA2-LogCs+gLpYoShhKJFAXdxwmRFYQDjpPEAAVACUAfQBJURAAR35KKFo2YkQkm3JkzWIsaituTMNjeO4AITT0zKxc-MLikGabGBgbOgrCKp5akvaQBtiTEuaAGQzpzryCyiKWgaG6RZwAM3Gatnw66dm4hMTl9o6c9Z7uRLL9o6yTs6mLozmmkpuGQAalkuhstgDXodjpMQOkQX5DCAYIUGAcbNQ6CxQOY3OZ+K4ggkIAd5IEYPw6AA6T6qAC8DNUAHJ0kzVKo1LwBMIALTycx4VzyLmCIQ6ZBaHlmSiWU62ewMLQc1QkslBSk0qz0xks1nszn5blCPkCiBCkXCcVaABUxulsusdiKiuVqvJGtpDLpzLubOVFuN-MFwsNoqt1oAzFKLFZ5c6lWo3erqZ6dfC-Qa+KKTcGA+HkNGZbGnQ4E6o2ATXFpq1ospQojws0xZrjXPjCTBiaT3SmtV6fRnVAHXd3k5rTtrvbrBwGc2aQ02xRKy0mKb2J-3dXr-aHeUH53mJbaV6O1+P8JOfUCZ7vA6bzbfwxGyxXXFWa3WG9RFzNfq320S3CrhqYI9JeTIvOUlSDqgI5qmeoGbDA4H9IMwyjEQg4AArpNaqBUl4cE9lSiFFChOzDG8MDYekRFjqRyGbpBVE0daACMBHKq+77Vp+3DwMEv44niBKASUwHUgx4GQRh1H6qoOF4ZxianiBjxIeRaEjNB8k4XRCHqWRm6obsLG6bhHGESp8Fqd0GlMVCRysUIXGVjWtZYPW-FEJQBj+CAdA0AA1qEyIAJ7kAkNDmFk8A4IJiCgBIUjcKgv4gOYNiuBi3DUDgUDpTgbCZXwpyhRaoUHBAOCuAVJTftyWQMK2nigFAwyUHILBkAGIC+PoSK9YlIBVTVdWNkaTUtaF7WBV10Q9befUDVgcUJaAo21d5glYM1bitSAs2dWw3VYIpIj9Uia2+ZV1VbSUAk3bt03DUd83MGQ53LUimXZdIw2beNVyxRFCRsMMchuFkrg4PgRV1dxz37TNHXvUkbRZK0KyY7cqxJLj9yAvCfXVJscMsDw+VZAAxMg5gAOwAByUIz9NeFk+B5UVNN00zLNeGlWC0wzzOM0I7OXQNQA)

I use this code:

```
"radius": {"field": "rdius", "scale": {"domain": [0, "radius2"]}},
"radius2": {"field": "rdius2", "scale": {"domain": [0, "radius2"]}},
"theta": {"field": "thta", "scale": {"domain": [0, "PI*2"]}},
"theta2": {"field": "thta2", "scale": {"domain": [0, "PI*2"]}},
```

Can someone help with the proper scaling?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The domain `[0, "radius2"]` is invalid. In place of `"radius2"` you either need to specify a number, or a valid expression without any data dependence, like `"PI * 2"`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and having a look at my question.

As I defined "radius2" as a parameter, and the signal viewer shows the expected result: 200 I conclude that params are considered data-dependent. Am I right?

Nevertheless, if I change the domain to [0, 200] still the are arcs will not be drawn as I would expect. I assume I miss something very fundamentally, sorry for that. Unfortunately I'm in the early beginnings of using vega-lite.